# "service sshd restart" failed to reconnect with remote host by ssh

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, openssh

I am trying to use ssh for logging in my remote host. However, I find that when i use command "service sshd restart" to restart my ssh, it will fail to reconnect. So, I reinstalled and config my  remote host and perform the same operator as following:

Before `service sshd restart`:

```
$ ssh root@106.55.170.166
Last login: Sat Jun 27 10:30:27 2020 from 223.88.133.240
[root@VM_0_17_centos ~]# exit
logout
Connection to 106.55.170.166 closed.
```

Everything is Ok.

After `service sshd restart`:

```
$ ssh root@106.55.170.166
Last login: Sat Jun 27 10:33:06 2020 from 223.88.133.240
[root@VM_0_17_centos ~]# vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config //reedit this file.
[root@VM_0_17_centos ~]# service sshd restart
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
[root@VM_0_17_centos ~]# exit
logout
Connection to 106.55.170.166 closed.
```

Now, fail to reconnect:

```
$ ssh root@106.55.170.166
ssh: connect to host 106.55.170.166 port 22: Connection refused
```

===================================

I only edited sshd_config file as following:

```
Banner /etc/issue
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [su]. When you do, it would be helpful for you to include the contents of sshd_config on the remote server and note specifically what changes you made.

Comment: @ Kenste I added more information.